# How to print the sql count in a view?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this

```
$noOfcomment = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(comment) as cs FROM comments WHERE placeid='$pid->placeid'");
```

But I don't know how to print the result in a view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `select` method will always return an `array` of results.

```
print_r($noOfcomment);
```

To print the count:

```
echo $noOfcomment[0]->cs;
```

To print the result in a view you have to pass a variable:

```
return View::make('viewName', array('count' => $noOfcomment[0]->cs));
```

Then print the result in your view:

```
<?php echo $count; ?>
```

To get more details about the database with Laravel, please check:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database

To get more details about view in Laravel, please check:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses

Comment: it says Undefined variable: noOfcomment, I want to print the result in my view

Comment: What is the result of print_r(DB::select("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 1"));

Comment: $noOfcomment = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(comment) as cs FROM comments WHERE placeid='$pid->placeid'"); 
this line was inside my route and I want to display the count result in my view

Comment: here's the result
    Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [userid] => 1 [placeid] => ChIJ38WHZwf9KysRUhNblaFnglM [comment] => comment1 [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ) ) 

of
     print_r(DB::select("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 1"));

Comment: What about: print_r(DB::select("SELECT COUNT(comment) as cs FROM comments WHERE placeid='$pid->placeid'"));

Comment: Try this plese: echo $noOfcomment[0]->cs;

Comment: it gives me correct result but I want to display the result in my view 'cause my sql was in routes

Comment: return $noOfcomment[0]->cs;

Comment: return view('viewName', ['count' => $noOfcomment[0]->cs]);

then print the value in the view:

<?php echo $count; ?>

Comment: it says Call to undefined function view()

Comment: return View::make('viewName', array('count' => $noOfcomment[0]->cs));

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Laravel Eloquent aggregate](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) function instead using the DB facade

```
$noOfcomments = Comment::where('placeid', your id here)->count();
```

To pass the data into a view

```
return view('viewname', compact('noOfcomments'));// and echo $noOfcomments variable in your view
```

Where as `SELECT` method returns an array and you are select a specific column then I assume you could access count variable like

```
$noOfcomment = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(comment) as cs FROM comments WHERE placeid='$pid->placeid'"); 
print_r($noOfcomment[0]->cs);
```

Comment: it gives me correct result but I want to display the result in my view 'cause my sql was in routes

Comment: it says Undefined variable: noOfcomment (View:

Comment: @user101 change variable users to noOfcomments and then print `echo $noOfcomments` in your view. See the updated answer.